# ERROR: there is no unique constraint matching given keys for referenced table "trans_part" in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

I have a partition partitioned table named "trans_part" and it's primary key is on `(id, created_date)` columns.

Date wise partitions are there on ***"created_date"*** column.

When I am creating a foreign key on another table "trans_escalation" with reference(id) column of "trans_part" then getting error as below.

```
ALTER TABLE trans_escalation ADD CONSTRAINT fk_trans FOREIGN KEY (alert_id) REFERENCES trans_part(id);
```

> ERROR: there is no unique constraint matching given keys for referenced table "alert_part" SQL state: 42830

How to resolve this issue?

Comment: Your sample code mentions `trans_part` but the error mentions `alert_part`.

Comment: its trans_part ... by mistake mentioned alert_part

Comment: A FK must reference a unique or primary key in the referenced table. The PK in `trans_part` is `(id, created_date)`; so by itself `id` is not unique. Your FK **must** include both columns. ;

Comment: But both columns are not there in both table, i.e. created_date is not in detail(trans_escalation) table